# PermissionError: [WinError 5] instead of IsADirectoryError

Tags: python, error-handling, operating-system

According to official documentation for the os module, IsADirectoryError is the exception which is raised when os.remove() is used on a directory.

I would expect the following code to create and delete a directory, but instead it errors:

```
>>> os.mkdir(r'C:\test')
>>> try:
...     os.remove(r'C:\test')
... except IsADirectoryError:
...     os.rmdir(r'C:\test')
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\test'
```

Why am I getting a permissions error instead of the expected IsADirectoryError?

Edit: Simply running os.rmdir(r'C:\test') works, so my script does have the access to delete the folder.

Edit:  It's been proposed that I catch WinError 5 and try dealing with it as a folder and if that doesn't work, continue to handle the other error possibilities for WinError 5.  As can be shown below, this can quickly create ugly code.  Is there a way to distinguish between the different errors raising a WinError 5 exception?  If not, is there a neater way to handle all the possible cases?

```
try:
    os.remove(r'C:\test')
except WindowsError as e:
    if e.winerror==5: #maybe it's a directory
        try: 
            os.rmdir(r'C:\test')
        except WindowsError as f:
            if f.winerror==5: #maybe it's read-only
                try:
                    os.chmod(r'C:\test', 0o777)
                except WindowsError as g:
                    if f.winerror==5: #maybe we don't have access
                    ...
```

Comment: because your script has no access to get stats of `C:\test` path

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Why doesn't it have access if it created the folder?  How do I give it access?

Comment: I guess because it is directly under `C:\ `. Try another path. Like your user folder. The `PermissionError` is raised before it is even checked to be a directory

Comment: @Tomerikoo I get the same result when doing it for C:\Users\myusername\test

Answer (score 0):

The docs (https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/exceptions.html) say IsADirectoryError corresponds to errno=EISDIR, so this is raised iff the OS returned EISDIR. Windows, when removing a directory with os.remove raises WindowsError instead, as Python doesn't get EISDIR from the OS as a response but something else. This can simply be handled:

```
try:
    os.remove(r'C:\test')
except WindowsError as e:
    if e.winerror == 5: # maybe we tried to remove a directory, so
        os.rmdir(r'C:\test')
    else:
        raise # we just re-raise whatever the exception was.
```

Comment: What if I actually am denied access?  How do I distinguish between the two errors?

Comment: try to run this against a directory you actually don't have permissions to, and see what exception you get. ;)

Comment: I get WinError 5 and During handling of about exception: WinError 5.  So, what, do I chain the try except if pattern for everything that WinError 5 could mean?

Answer (score 0):

What I found out is sometime the file in system will automatically comes with *"read only"* attribute, and you will need to remove "read only" before you using `os.remove` or `shutil.move`:

```
# the '-r' means remove
os.system(f"attrib -r {full_file_path}")
os.remove(full_file_path)
```